# NextJS not-found.tsx returns HTTP 200 Status Code

Tags: next.js, http-status-code-404

When I use NextJS's not-found.tsx file, it renders fine but it returns a 200 status code instead of 404. Any idea why? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think since you are returning a valid custom component, it sets it as 200.

If you delete `not-found.tsx` and use this

```
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'
```

inside the component

```
if(true) notFound()
```

if you hover over `notFound`

> When used in a React server component, this will set the status code
> to 404. When used in a custom app route it will just send a 404
> status.

Comment: I read this a few times and the documentation a few times and I finally found what was wrong. The component where I called notFound() from had 'use client' which made it a client component. A server component is the only one that can return a 404 status.

Thanks Yilmaz

Answer (score 1):

Another potential cause, the one that i ran into is that if you are using a loading.js suspense page in your app route it turns your 404s into client responses, I couldn't find this anywhere in the nextjs documentation for the loading component https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/loading.

But I tried removing the loading.js file and it worked, i now have the correct http codes being returned.